# NetOffice - add-in not loading

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, netoffice

I'm developing an Outlook add-in using the NetOffice library.
It was a nice experience, but lastly I changed my drive, reinstalled windows, office etc.
Now my add in doesn't run, and in the "COM Add-Ins" in Outlook options I see:
`Load Behavior: Not loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in`

And this problem is even on the simples example from NetOffice, that is the `NetOffice Tools - Simple` project, which basically doesn't do anything.

I put in the constructor of the add in a logging code (to a file), but it doesn't run, so even the constructor isn't hit.

Any tips how to troubleshoot it?

EDIT: using AddInSpy I found out, that the Add-in status is:
`Add-in DLL path is not found.`
but no idea how to move on with this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked it out! :)

After reinstalling windows, I installed Office 2013 *64 bit* whereas earlier I had the *32 bit* version, that caused a lot of trouble.

To run it on 64 bit:

- Target 64 bit when compiling the add-in (AnyCPU is not enough!)
- VS can use the 32 bit regasm, so add to the post build event following line:
  `"%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm" "$(TargetPath)"`

and it works again.

Comment: Are there any tutorials of putting together *and* debugging a simple Word add-in via NetOffice?  I'm really struggling with the lack of documentation...unless I should just be following VSTO documentation since NetOffice seems to be trying to emulate that?